# Compiling an old version of inetutils in a VM

Tags: compiling

I have to compile `inetutils` 1.4.

The current iteration of `gcc` gives errors and I don't want to try installing an older `gcc`, so I think my best bet is to start a VM and compile it there.

I don't care if I can't run the compiled programs on my host, I just need to run them locally in the VM.

Is this a reasonable plan?

Which distribution is likely to successfully compile inetutils from ~2002?

Comment: Can you share some of those errors?

Comment: `ttymsg.c:135:30: error: lvalue required as left operand of assigment` Please note that I have absolutely zero interest in trying to make a 17 year old program compile with gcc 7.4. I would much rather use a build environment that it was intended to work with.

Comment: gcc 9.1.0 shows many errors, most of them are missing include headers. So, it may be possible to fix those manually. e.g. the `ttymsg.c:135:30: error` can be fixed with `iov->iov_base = (void*)((char*)iov->iov_base + wret);`. You can try old Debian releases.